# Default documentroot served from url localhost

Tags: apache-2.4

I have compiled apache 2.4 to Ubuntu Linux desktop and configured `DocumentRoot` directive to point to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`. Instead of serving `index.html` in configured `DocumentRoot`, apache keeps looking into `/var/www`. Am I missing some configuration?

It seems that apache server actual index page from `/var/www` when I use alias `localhost` as url, and when using `127.0.0.1` it serves directory index from `DocumentRoot` directory

Target is to configure apache to serve directory index from `DocumentRoot` under localhost url

Actual configuration:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
< Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
  Options +Indexes
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
< /Directory>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and I swear, I've solved it before, but it's been so long since I used apache that I can't remember what the fix was :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ServerName directive to use name based virtual hosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
ServerName localhost

<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted

    # turn Magento developer mode on
    # SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1;

</Directory>
```

Make sure localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1
Make sure that there is an index.html file in your web root

Restart apache

```
apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thx, i did more digging and there is explanation about virtual hosts

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: It worked, thank You !